# Using popen() to upload ardiuno sketch

Tags: php, file-upload, arduino

I am trying to use PHP to compile and upload an Arduino sketch through the command line. Right now a user uploads an `ino` or `pde` file through a form and it is transferred to a directory for later use. Using the uploaded file's location as a variable, I would like PHP to run the command line version of Ardunio to compile and upload it.

After an inital try with using `exec()` and `system()`, I switched to `popen()`. Running the following code I can get Arduino to open then it closes without uploading the sketch:

```
pclose(popen('"C:\Program Files\Arduino\arduino.exe" --port COM3 --upload "C:\sketches\uploads\cube\a\a.ino"));
```

Running that code and its variations through the Windows Command Line works so I know the input string is not the issue. Also, looking at the Windows Task Manager shows it opening for a second or so then closing. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For `popen` (or any of the other process functions) to work correctly on Windows [you need to escape backslashes](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/2) like this:

```
pclose(popen('"C:\\Program Files\\Arduino\\arduino.exe" --port COM3 --upload "C:\\sketches\\uploads\\cube\\a\\a.ino"'));
```

alternatively try replacing the backslashes with forward slashes. The following should also work on recent versions of Windows:

```
pclose(popen('"C:/Program Files/Arduino/arduino.exe" --port COM3 --upload "C:/sketches/uploads/cube/a/a.ino"'));
```

(Your code snippet was also missing a trailing single quote, but I suspect that's a typo.)

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation, I now know why and how to escape backslashes. However, the problem is still happening. I now think it has more to do with Arduino than the PHP side of things... Watching task manager shows arduino (as a javaw.exe) process running at system level as that's what Wamp runs as, then just before the upload it quits